# maven plugin to call or invoke a rest web service

Tags: plugins, maven

Is there any maven plugin which will be invoking already existing rest web service? or else is there any way to invoke a web service in pom.xml. 
    like we have for invoking a external command
    org.codehaus.mojo
            exec-maven-plugin
            1.2
please help me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need invoke a REST service using a POST method, you can use a groovy script

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myspotontheweb.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-rest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder</groupId>
            <artifactId>http-builder</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute</goal>
                      </goals>
                       <configuration>
                          <source>
                            import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
                            import groovy.util.slurpersupport.GPathResult
                            import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.XML

                            solr = new RESTClient('http://localhost:8080/solr/update')

                            def response = solr.post(
                                contentType: XML,
                                requestContentType: XML,
                                body: {
                                    add {
                                        doc {
                                            field(name:"id", "SOLR1000")
                                            field(name:"name", "Solr, the Enterprise Search Server")
                                            field(name:"manu", "Apache Software Foundation")
                                            field(name:"cat", "software")
                                            field(name:"cat", "search")
                                            field(name:"features", "Advanced Full-Text Search Capabilities using Lucene")
                                            field(name:"features", "Optimized for High Volume Web Traffic")
                                            field(name:"features", "Standards Based Open Interfaces - XML and HTTP")
                                            field(name:"features", "Comprehensive HTML Administration Interfaces")
                                            field(name:"features", "Scalability - Efficient Replication to other Solr Search Servers")
                                            field(name:"features", "Flexible and Adaptable with XML configuration and Schema")
                                            field(name:"features", "Good unicode support: héllo (hello with an accent over the e)")
                                            field(name:"price", "0")
                                            field(name:"popularity", "10")
                                            field(name:"inStock", "true")
                                            field(name:"incubationdate_dt", "2006-01-17T00:00:00.000Z")
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            )
                            log.info "Solr response status: ${response.status}"
                         </source>
                     </configuration>
                 </execution>
              </executions>
         </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The [REST API example](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/03/use-restclient-to-post-and-read-xml.html) was taken from Hubert Klein Ikkink's blog:

http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/

Comment: is it possible to extract the groovy code into a file?

Comment: Of course, while you at it, simply load the file from within Groovy Script and eval it. :)

Comment: @aurelius Yes. My example shows an inline script, can alternatively list a file path or URL. See the plugin documentation here: https://groovy.github.io/gmaven/groovy-maven-plugin/execute-mojo.html

Answer (score 3):

You can call REST web service using [Ant's Get task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/get.html) (though it's limited to only GET method). And use [Maven's Antrun plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) to call your Ant script.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [rest-maven-plugin](https://github.com/cjnygard/rest-maven-plugin) to perform either a POST or a GET (and other methods such as PATCH or PUT would probably work as well).

The plugin can POST a file and also save the results returned from the REST request to a file, with normal maven support for filesets and remapping the resulting filenames relative to the POSTed file.

It will also support pure GET request with the results stored to a specific file.

Standard REST query properties are supported, such as setting Query parameters, Header parameters, and Request/Response media types.

See for the code.  The latest release version of the maven plugin is also published and available via normal Sonatype Nexus repository.

Here's an example where JSON Schema document is submitted to a NodeJS REST service which will return JSON sample data generated by the Faker module.  It will upload all the files in the ./target/classes/json/faker directory which match '*.json' and deposit the results into the ./target/classes/json/examples directory.

Check out the example below.

```
<properties>
  <rest-maven-plugin.version>1.4</rest-maven-plugin.version>
</properties>

<plugins>
  <plugin>
     <groupId>com.github.cjnygard</groupId>
     <artifactId>rest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>${rest-maven-plugin.version}</version>
     <executions>
       <execution>
         <id>fake-json-data</id>
         <phase>process-classes</phase>
         <goals>
           <goal>rest-request</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
           <endpoint>${json-data-server.url}</endpoint>
           <resource>schema/v1/api</resource>
           <queryParams>
             <addRequired>1</addRequired>
           </queryParams>
           <fileset>
             <directory>${project.build.resourcepath}/json/faker</directory>
             <includes>
              <include>*.json</include>
             </includes>
           </fileset>
           <requestType>
             <type>application</type>
             <subtype>json</subtype>
           </requestType>
           <responseType>
             <type>application</type>
             <subtype>json</subtype>
           </responseType>
           <outputDir>${project.build.resourcepath}/md/json/examples</outputDir>            
         </configuration>
       </execution>
     </executions>
   </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: You should mention, that you are the author of this plugin.

Comment: this plugin works well, except this is a pain to keep your cookies between 2 calls. My service requires me to first call a "login" action, then invoke another method on a resource, with the session cookie , and I don't know how to do it with your plugin....

Answer (score 0):

To give an example of the Antrun Maven Plugin solution:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>notify</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals><goal>run</goal></goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <get dest="target/counter" usetimestamp="false" 
                              src="https://c1.navrcholu.cz/hit?site=144925;t=lb14;ref=;jss=0"
                              verbose="off" quiet="true" ignoreerrors="true"/>
                        </target>
                        <failOnError>false</failOnError>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed support for an untrusted HTTPs connection and none of the above approaches was supporting this easily. I found the [Java curl](https://github.com/libetl/curl) library. Ant's Get task is nice but does not support this. The Java curl library is also offering a wider range of options and HTTP methods. For my purposes I have used this solution together with the Groovy Maven plugin:

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>execute</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <source>
                                    import static org.toilelibre.libe.curl.Curl.$;

                                    try {
                                        $("curl -k " +
                                                "-o target/openapi.json https://localhost:1234/openapi");
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception e) {
                                        System.err.println(e)
                                    }
                                </source>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.toile-libre.libe</groupId>
                            <artifactId>curl</artifactId>
                            <version>0.0.29</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
```