# Recommended way for consuming a REST API using Maven?

Tags: rest, maven

What's the recommended way for consuming a REST API using Maven?

The newest answer I found (from 2014) says it's using an embedded Groovy script - 
[Making HTTP requests during maven archetype:generate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399328/making-http-requests-during-maven-archetypegenerate)

Is this still the best way to do this?

(My usecase is uploading and deploying an application using the Oracle Cloud REST APIs)

I'm new to both REST and Maven, so if this question just doesn't make sense, it would be interesting to know why. 
I guess making a generic REST consuming plugin might be tricky, almost requiring it's own DSL.
But if I just want to make the calls, and don't care so much about the responses, is there no Maven http plugin to use?

Comment: R u saying you want to do a Rest call during a build ? Or just consume it normally. And in which language are you looking for?

Comment: My thoughts were that I would deploy our application to the cloud using a REST API during some optional build phase. Maybe I will end up doing something completely different, letting Jenkins do the deploy or do it manually....